# SQL to select rows where at least one row in a group, has a corresponding entry in another table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

```
Table1: FieldA, FieldB
Table2: FieldA
```

`Table1` is grouped by `FieldB`, and `FieldA` is the link between the two tables.

For each grouping in `Table1`, if all rows in that group do not have an entry in `Table2`, then return no rows corresponding to this group. If at least one row in the group has an entry in `Table2`, then return all rows in the group.

Is this kind of query possible?

Thanks

Simon

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't a simple INNER JOIN resolve this?

Comment: The inner join will return the rows that exist in both `Table1` and `Table2`, ignoring the grouping criteria. For example, if I have three rows in `Table1`, which are part of the same group, and only one of the three rows exists in `Table2`, I still would like to return all three rows from `Table1`

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you need to do a simple inner join:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.FieldA=t2.FieldA;
```

I'm unclear from your question if the values in Table2 are unique. If they are not unique then this subquery might work better:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE FieldA in (SELECT distinct(FieldA) FROM Table2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, this `JOIN` would to do it;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1a.*
FROM Table1 t1a
JOIN Table1 t1b
  ON t1a.FieldB = t1b.FieldB
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t2.FieldA=t1b.FieldA;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ddaf3/2).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE FieldB IN (
  SELECT t1.FieldB
  FROM Table1 t1
  JOIN Table2 t2
    ON t1.FieldA = t2.FieldA
  GROUP BY t1.FieldB
)
```